# Using pandas .loc with date in combination with different datetimeindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just realized a "different behavior" of the `.loc` function by accessing dataframes with different `datetimeindex` format.

Given the 2 `dataframes` below:

```
df1
datetimeindex  value
2020-10-01     50.1
2020-10-02     50.2
2020-10-03     50.3
2020-10-04     50.4
2020-10-05     50.5
2020-10-06     50.6
2020-10-07     50.7


df2
datetimeindex            value
2020-10-01 09:45:07      50.1
2020-10-02 09:45:07      50.2
2020-10-03 09:45:07      50.3
2020-10-04 09:45:07      50.4
2020-10-05 09:45:07      50.5
2020-10-06 09:45:07      50.6
2020-10-07 09:45:07      50.7
2020-10-08 09:45:07      50.8
```

If I now apply the `.loc` function with the exact same input, I get different results.

```
sdate = date(2020, 10, 1)
edate = date(2020, 10, 5)

df1.loc[sdate:edate]
datetimeindex  value
2020-10-01     50.1
2020-10-02     50.2
2020-10-03     50.3
2020-10-04     50.4
2020-10-05     50.5

df2.loc[sdate:edate]
df2
datetimeindex            value
2020-10-01 09:45:07      50.1
2020-10-02 09:45:07      50.2
2020-10-03 09:45:07      50.3
2020-10-04 09:45:07      50.4
```

I believe this behavior is because the `date(2020, 10, 5)` will be handled as `2020-10-05 00:00:00` and by that the `2020-10-05` line of `df2` seems to be excluded.

Currently I am helping myself out by using `timedelta` for `df2`. So I am accessing `df2` with `df2.loc[sdate:(edate + timedelta(days=1))]`.

I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to compensate this behavior or if I am completely wrong anyway.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct about this datetime behaviour. You can solve this by using [`DatetimeIndex.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.round.html) on `df2`:

```
df2.index = df2.index.round('D')
```